# Iterate through multiple elements of querySelectorAll with forEach

Tags: javascript, foreach, jquery-selectors, addeventlistener

The problem is as following: I have created a separate JS file, in which I want to iterate through elements belonging to a certain class `audioz`. In the second line of my JS code I use the `addEventListener` on `item`, however the code does not seem to work with `item`, only if I put `document`, but the result remains flawed. What am I doing wrong in the iteration?

JS:

```js
document.querySelectorAll('.audioz').forEach(item => {
    item.addEventListener('keydown', function(e) {
        const ss = document.querySelector(`audio[data-key="${e.keyCode}"]`);
        console.log(ss);
        ss.play();
    })
})
```

HTML:

```html
<audio class="audioz" data-key="65" src="sounds/clap.wav"></audio>
<audio class="audioz" data-key="83" src="sounds/hihat.wav"></audio>
<audio class="audioz" data-key="68" src="sounds/kick.wav"></audio>
<audio class="audioz" data-key="70" src="sounds/openhat.wav"></audio>
<audio class="audioz" data-key="71" src="sounds/boom.wav"></audio>
<audio class="audioz" data-key="72" src="sounds/ride.wav"></audio>
<audio class="audioz" data-key="74" src="sounds/snare.wav"></audio>
<audio class="audioz" data-key="75" src="sounds/tom.wav"></audio>
<audio class="audioz" data-key="76" src="sounds/tink.wav"></audio>
```

Comment: The `audio` tag is hidden. You can't execute the `keydown` event on it.

Comment: Try to break this down one step at a time. You are doing a query all for elements of a certain class. For each result you are creating a listener to console log only the results of another query. Is the internal loop doing what you expect?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are currently adding a `keydown` event listener to each `audio` tag. However, the `audio` tag is hidden, so you can't execute the `keydown` event on it. Thus, your code will not work.

Add the event listener to the document instead.

```js
document.addEventListener('keydown', function(e) {
  const ss = document.querySelector(`audio[data-key="${e.keyCode}"]`);
  console.log(ss);
  ss.play();
})
```

```html
<audio class="audioz" data-key="65" src="https://interactive-examples.mdn.mozilla.net/media/cc0-audio/t-rex-roar.mp3"></audio> press the A key
```

Answer (score 1):

You can attach a listener to the parent element for each `<audio>`. This avoids some pollution of events at the document level.

```js
const audiozResults = document.getElementsByClassName("audioz");
for (const result of audiozResults) {
  const dataKey = +result.getAttribute("data-key");
  result.parentElement.addEventListener("keydown", evt => {
    if (evt.keyCode === dataKey) {
      result.play();
    }
  });
}
```

```html
<audio class="audioz" data-key="65" src="https://interactive-examples.mdn.mozilla.net/media/cc0-audio/t-rex-roar.mp3"></audio> press the A key
```